# Close a file created using GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal

I have problems to close a file created in GDAL

I have the following code (it's a part of bigger piece of code):

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
SAL01=driver. Create(Fnout1,afile.shape[1],afile.shape[0],1,tipoarr)
SAL01.SetProjection(proj)
SAL01.SetGeoTransform(trans)
SAL01.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(10000)
band = SAL01.GetRasterBand(1)
band.WriteArray(afile)
band.FlushCache()
band.ComputeStatistics(False)
Fnout.close()
```

The error when process Fnout.close() is 'str' object has no attribute 'close'

In fact, Fnout is a string (used to generate the file name) and not a 'file' object.

Any simple way to close the file using the string as reference?

Comment: Please *always* include the version of whatever software you are using when asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For gdal >= 3.8:

Use [`Close`](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Dataset.Close) not `close` (case sensitive). Or use a `with` statement as 3.8 `Dataset` objects support context managers.

```
SAL01.Close()
```

If using an older gdal, delete or set `SAL01` to `None` to dereference it. The dataset will be closed and written.

```
SAL01 = None
# or
del SAL01
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. Appear the message 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'Close'

Comment: @Eduardo see edit

Comment: Thanks!!!. SAL01=None works!